# How to convert leftouterjoin query into LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have a sql query which has innerjoin and leftouter join's which is very tricky to mr to convert to LINQ.

```sql
SELECT project.ID, project.No, project.Name,  
       APPLN.Id,APPLN.Name,SAR.Name  
FROM Phasefact phase WITH (NOLOCK)  
INNER JOIN AProject project WITH (NOLOCK) on phase.Id = project.ID
INNER JOIN Application APPLN WITH (NOLOCK) ON project.AppId = APPLN.Id
LEFT OUTER JOIN Master master WITH (NOLOCK) ON phase.amId = master.Id
INNER JOIN Ref SAR WITH (NOLOCK) ON SAR.ID = master.Ref_Id
WHERE phase.ID = 123
```

It is bit confusing as it contains "left outer join". Someone please help.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this:

```
var result=(
        from phase in db.Phasefact
        join project in db.AProject
            on phase.Id equals project.ID
        join APPLN in db.Application 
            on project.AppId equals APPLN.Id
        //Left join
        from master in db.Master
            .Where(a=>a.Id==phase.amId).DefaultIfEmpty()
        join SAR in db.Ref
            on SAR.ID equals master.Ref_Id
        where phase.ID == 123 
        select new
        {
            project.ID,
            project.No,
            project.Name,  
            APPLN.Id,
            APPLN.Name,
            SAR.Name
        }
    );
```

**EDIT**

But i don't get the `left join`. Why are you using a `left join`? To me it looks like you first use a `left join`:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN Master master WITH (NOLOCK) ON phase.amId = master.Id
```

And the after that you have a join that limits the result like this:

```
INNER JOIN Ref SAR WITH (NOLOCK) ON SAR.ID = master.Ref_Id
```

This will be the same as doing this:

```
INNER JOIN Master master WITH (NOLOCK) ON phase.amId = master.Id
INNER JOIN Ref SAR WITH (NOLOCK) ON SAR.ID = master.Ref_Id
```

Answer (score 0):

I am giving you an basic idea of left outer join in LINQ

> var lines = from p in db.Phasefact
>   join m in db.Master on m.Id equals
>   p.amId into p_m 
>   where p.ID == 123 
>   from m in p_m.DefaultIfEmpty()
>   select new { p.ID };

Now you can convert this much more according to your logic... or Query.......